# How to access SAP2000's OpenAPI in PyWin32

Tags: python, vba, pywin32

Python Win32 extensions can work with Microsoft Office applications, such as Word and Excel, using the `pywin32com.clients.Dispatch()` function call. There are other applications that can be similarly accessed using VBA. One such software is SAP2000 (Computers and Structures Inc.) which offers what it calls OpenAPI.

**How can I access SAP2000's OpenAPI in Python Win32 extensions?**

A typical VBA function to open SAP2000 from inside Excel goes as follows:

```
Dim SapObject As Sap2000.SapObject    
Dim ret As Long

Sub SAP2000_open()
    Set SapObject = New Sap2000.SapObject
    SapObject.ApplicationStart
    SapObject.SapModel.InitializeNewModel (lb_ft_F)
    ret = SapObject.SapModel.File.NewBlank
End Sub
```

The above subroutine when run by attaching it to a button click event opens SAP2000.

Comment: Can you instantiate an instance of Sap2000.SapObject with a CreateObject call from within VBA? .ie something like dim sapObj As Object; Set sapObj = CreateObject("Sap2000.SapObject")?

Answer (score 0):

In the installation directory of SAP2000, there is a file named CSI_OAPI_Documentation.chm (for versions before 20, the file name might be slightly different) and by reading it you can access almost everything needed for using the API of SAP2000.

Answer (score -1):

See the CSI OAPI Doc.

1. Download and install Python 3.0 or higher for Windows. Python is freely available at python.org.
2. Download and install "Python for Windows extensions." It is freely available from sourceforge.net.
3. Create a Python .py file using the PythonWin IDE or any text editor and paste in the following code:
   ......